# It display a link twice, not once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code below where the problem is that it displays the `<span>` tag "Open Grid" twice when it should only display it once:

```
$('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $optionsText = $("<div>Option Type:</div><input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />")
.attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val())
.appendTo( $options )
.after("<span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>");

$questionType = $this.val();

});
```

Now if I remove the `<div>` tags around the string "Option Type" then it displays the "Open Grid" link once but then the string "Option Type" isn't displayed.

So how can I display "Option Type:" but making sure it displays "Open Grid" link only once?

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnbsV/2/). Just click on the "Add Question" button and you will see what is happening

Comment: No clue if it matters, but `<span>` can't have `href`

Comment: tag your question more specific

Comment: Can you set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have included jsfiddle in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/hnbsV/3/

Comment: What did you change? I included the code at the bottom of your fiddle but this displays three "Open Grid", thats why I am wondering if I missed something?

Comment: You beat me to it! ;).  Look at the line where you define `$optionsText`. `$optionsText` equals a jQuery array with **2** elements: the div element saying "Option Type" and the input element. Therefore, when you do `.after`, you are really telling it to append the "[Open Grid]" text after **both** the div and the input element. He added the `:last` selector to fix that.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help :) Upvote comment and answer and obviously best answer

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up @SethAlexanderBird while i was afk :]